# Vertically aligning a div using vh

Tags: html, css

I set my wrapper's height to 100vh to fill up the entire screen and then inside the wrapper I wanted a div to be set to 50% - vertically in the middle and used position: relative and set top / transform (translateY) to 50%. It works perfectly on my desktop computer, but when displaying on my macbook (both running Chrome) it doesn't display correctly and is "pushed" to maybe 30% of screen height. What am I doing wrong ? Here is my code:

```
#main-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;  
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e1484f 50%, #f9f9f9 50%);
}
#info-left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    float: left;    
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your inner div this way:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

It will center horizontally and vertically your div.

Do not forget the `-webkit` for a good cross-browsing exerience.

Comment: That's just adding cross-browser support and horizontally aligning it, that's not what I want. As I wrote I wanted to vertically align it to the middle, and my code is working on my desktop computer but not my laptop